# React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

imports feitas para rodar o codigo,

```
//aplicaçoes importadas...
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';

//paginas importadas...
import Login from './pages/login/login';
import Register from './pages/register/register';
import Main from './pages/main/main'
import Showcase from './pages/showcase/showcase'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { isAuthenticated } from "./config/isautheticated";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

problemas do código aqui, aqui gostaria de passar os estados como propriedados para o componente Main e um função de set para o componente login.

```
const [playload,setplayload]=useState();

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/login"><Login ATT={setplayload()}/></Route>
    <Route exact={true} path="/register" component={Register}/>
    <Route exact={true} path="/showcase" component={Showcase}/>
    <PrivateRoute path="/main"><Main props={playload}/></PrivateRoute>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: I think the question is quite clear by the heading.

Answer (score 4):

`const [playload,setplayload]=useState();`

This line is not inside a react function component.

You  should move it to an existing component where you want to keep this `playLoad` state or create a new Wrapper component for all your routes that'll hold this state, like

```
    export default function App() {

     const [playload,setplayload] = useState();
    
      return (
         <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/login"><Login ATT={setplayload()}/></Route>
            <Route exact={true} path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route exact={true} path="/showcase" component={Showcase}/>
            <PrivateRoute path="/main"><Main props={playload}/></PrivateRoute>
          </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
```

And

```
ReactDOM.render(<App></App>, document.getElementById('root'));
```